# R- Ifelse inside a for loop with possible combinatorics

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement, combinatorics

I'm having a bit of trouble coding a conditional variable. This is a bit difficult to explain and some/most of my provided code is pseudo in a sense...I'm trying to explain my logic and what I want to happen. I'm using R studio with R v.3.3 as base on a windows 7 PC.

I'd like to create a variable "member_engagement_level" based on the values of 21 character variables.

I tried hard-coding the ifelse statements but it's so kludgy and lengthy that I just can't go ahead with it.

I think creating a function that uses combinatorics inside a for loop and an ifelse statement can accomplish this?...

Here's a snippet of my hard-coded ifelse (to give you an idea of the volume) also, I didn't use the choose function in R to create the combos, just hard-coded:

```
page$member_engagement_level<-ifelse(page$event1 != "" | page$event2 != "" |
                                    {19 more statements with | operator} ,"minimum",
                                     ifelse( {21 statements} , "medium",
                                          ifelse( {21 statements with & and | operator}, "high",
                                              ifelse({56 statements include combination of events (total statements = 1 + from 4 events choose 2 + from 8 events choose 2 + from 7 events choose 2 = 1 + 6 + 28 + 21)}, "very high",
                                                   ifelse({96 statements (1 + 4 choose 3 + 8 choose 3 + 7 choose 3 = 82)}, "max", "")))))
```

As you can tell hard-coding this logic gets very long and not easy to look at and work through

I'd really like a concise function, but I'm confused on to how to use the for loop and ifelse statement in conjunction with each other (haven't found anything online to help with this part of the problem). For instance just for the "member_engagement_level" = "minimum" level,

```
engaged<-function (X) { for (i in 1:ncol(major_event_vars) {
                       level<- ifelse(X[[i]] != "" | 
                                for (j in 1:ncol(involve_vars) {
                                      ifelse(X[[j]] == "I did this" | ...
                                          "minimum", "")
                        return(level)
                      } 
                    }
                   }
```

That is, the statement = true if any of the X[[i]] != "" or =="I did this" or %in% c("Always", 'Often"). The ifelses nor the for loops should be nested for a given level of "member_engagement_level"! (even though it's written as such here)
I know this won't work as is, but I'd like to highlight my trouble here.
1.) How do I concisely write the conditional to iterate over all the desired vars with the | and & operators, furthermore, the condition is different for some vars (the statement = true will be valid for inputs != "", == "I did this", and %in% c("Always", Often))

2.) for the combination statements...how do I incorporate that into the for loops and ifelse statements (if those in themselves are possible)? 
I'd like it to be something of the sort (this is real pseudo code, I really don't even know where to start):

```
    for (event in 1:(specific_event_cateogry)) { 
        ifelse((x[[event]] %in% c("Always", "Often") & X[[event+1]] %in% 
              c("Always", "Often")) | ((x[[event]] %in% c("Always", "Often") 
              & X[[event+2]] %in% c("Always", "Often")) | ... | (X[[event +
              (ncol(specific_event_category) - 1)]] %in% c("Always", 
              "Often") & x[[event + ncol(specific_event_category)]] %in% 
              c("Always","Often")), "high", ~more ifelse statements~)
```

For the above block there should be 7 choose 2 statements separated by the | operator. Can I shorten this with the choose function? (I know the way the for loop with X[[event+i]] is wrong, I just wanted to show my logic, but please help with that too!)

I understand this question itself is a bit confusing so please ask any questions and I'll try to clarify. Any help is much appreciated. Or pointing me in the right direction...

Thanks!

-John

Comment: Please simplify your problem, provide example data and expected output.

Comment: `page$event1 != "" | page$event2 != "" | {19 more statements with | operator}` could probably be replaced with something like `rowSums(is.na(xxx)) == 0`

Comment: @J.Collins  Also take a look at `case_when` from the `dplyr` package. It can be a good replacement for nested `ifelse`.

Comment: You, also, might try starting from the last `ifelse` statement and testing it with made up data that should throw TRUE and made up data that should return FALSE and work your way out. You can usually create simpler loops if you figure out what the intermediate data between steps will be and test them outside of loops, then build the loops one condition at a time. And test one at a time.If you learn to use `dplyr` and `tidyr` well, you can probably do a lot of the filtering, sorting and separating using pipes before you have to go to a `for` loop.